# IFS delimiter containing a space?

Tags: bash, ifs

Is it possible to set the IFS to " ,"? Thats a space and comma.

If I have it just as the comma I get this

```
genres="platform, action adventure, puzzle"
IFS=$','
for g in $genres
do
echo "$g"
done
platform
 action adventure
 puzzle
```

If I try setting it with the space it splits at single spaces also.

```
genres="platform, action adventure, puzzle"
IFS=$' ,'    
for g in $genres
do
echo "$g"
done
platform
action
adventure
puzzle
```

I'm sure I could clean the leading whitespace before or after the loop, but why can't I do it with the delimiter?

Comment: The "why" is that `IFS` is a *collection* of characters, each of which is individually a delimiter.

Comment: No, each character in IFS is parsed separately. Also `$','` is equal to `','` and `$' ,'` is just `' ,'`.

Comment: OK thanks guys. I'll just clean the array before.